# Assume a machine has a 100K logical address. The physical address is 30K and the page size is 4K

Tags: operating-system, paging

Assume a machine has a 100K logical address. The physical address is 30K and
the page size is 4K. Give the best answer to each of the following that you can

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a blatant no-effort homework/exam dump.

Comment: @MartinJames it's not homework. I also tried some problems like this type. But those questions had LA in x bit or address like 128/64 (power of 2) but here 100K, 30K, etc. So I am still confused. that's why I am here.

Answer (score 1):

It's implied they're powers of 2 due, so  100k -> 2^17, 30k -> 2^15, 4k -> 2^12. you can easily solve the rest yourself.